# Generate Report object in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, object

I have a requirement of generating the `rdl` in runtime. so I converted the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition` xsd to class and I need to create object for Report class with that it has lot of classes. I am struggling in the report generation using objects

I don't know how to assign values

```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Author", typeof(string))]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AutoRefresh", typeof(uint))]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Body", typeof(BodyType))]


 private ItemsChoiceType37[] itemsElementNameField;
```

Please help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wow are you going to render the RDL as a report?

Comment: yes I have generated it. not Curosity

Comment: But what are you going to with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is something like

```
List<object> items = new List<object>();
List<ItemsChoiceType37> itemChoices = new List<ItemsChoiceType37>();



//Author
items.Add("Author name");
itemChoices.Add(ItemsChoiceType37.Author);

items.Add(description);
itemChoices.Add(ItemsChoiceType37.Description);

//Width
items.Add("11in");
itemChoices.Add(ItemsChoiceType37.Width);

.
.
.

Report report = new Report();
report.Items = items.ToArray();
report.ItemsElementName = itemChoices.ToArray();
```

I hope it may help you